# Python flask application unable to load local images from dynamic HTML template

Tags: python, flask

I have python application one of the method returning list of file names in JSON format. I tried to bind the file names to  local folder path when I render the template images are not loading in browser.

I tried several ways to bind the path

```
img src="./localpath/filename.png"



img src="localpath/filename.png"



imagename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'foldername/'+ filename.png)
```

Even i tried to load image with local host static path but still unable to load images.
[image]
Can some one help me out on this?

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Flask serves static content from the `static` folder of your project. You can then create URLs for these files using `url_for('static', filename='image.png')` (assuming the location `static/image.png`, [see also](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#static-files)).

Please note that [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) should be your go-to way of building URLs as it takes a lot of tasks off your plate.

Answer (score 1):

Flask serves images through the static folder. So add filename.png in a folder called static and reference it from there.